# Wait until particular element to disappear

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Using Ruby, we can wait for particular element by doing following:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { driver.find_element(:class, 'gritter-item') }
```

but if I want particular element to disappear from DOM, I write method like:

```
  def disappear_element
    begin
      driver.find_element(:class, 'gritter-item')
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

and called it like:

```
wait.until { disappear_element }
```

This way I could achieve absence of element. Is there any better way in Ruby to achieve the same?

Comment: element disappear means ? I didn't get your point..

Comment: means expectation of element not found error. In my case, I want to check popup element is not found once popup disappears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `disappear_element` as follow (using `find_elements` instead of `find_element`):

```
def disappear_element
  driver.find_elements(:class, 'gritter-item').size == 0
end
```